# Gulp Watch not working

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I'm using Gulp to dome some tasks on my SCSS and CSS. Now the problem is that when I run Gulp it's starting the watch but nothing is happening: no css is being created. I triple checked the folder structure and it's can.

This is my code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('resources/assets/sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass({errLogToConsole: true}))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 version']}))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'))
});

gulp.task('default', function () {

    watch('resources/assets/sass/**/*.scss', function () {
        gulp.start('sass');
    });

});
```

## Temporary Solution

After a long search with some people it's just **PHPStorm** that's not showing the updated file. The file has to be accessed first. It's like a sort of caching.

When I save the .scss file, and immediatly open it with notepad, or access a php file which uses the file, then it also updates in PHPStorm.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('resources/assets/sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass({errLogToConsole: true}))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 version']}))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'))
});

gulp.task('default', function () {

    gulp.watch('resources/assets/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);

});
```

I don't think you really need another plugin to complie your sass files, `gulp.watch` works just fine.

So basically what I am doing here is, I am just telling gulp to watch all the sass files in that folder and whenever there's a change, just run the task in the given array `['sass']`.

Answer (score 1):

### The solution is a PHPStorm Setting

It seems that PHPStorm uses a form of file caching, that's why I didn't see the reflected changes. The solution can be found here!

[How to prevent phpstorm to reload file without prompt when file on disk is changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621166/how-to-prevent-phpstorm-to-reload-file-without-prompt-when-file-on-disk-is-chang)