# Disable File Cache Conflict dialog in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

I'm working on an Angular 2 application. Every time I perform a save, WebStorm prompts me to load the changes. It is becoming a rather tedious problem, as it does it every time I make a change to a TypeScript file. Here is a photo of this madness:

[image]

I cannot for the life of me find a clickable location in the IDE to set the default option. Has anyone ran into this issue, and if so, how did you fix it?

> WebStorm 2016.2.3
>   Build #WS-162.1812.21

Comment: See this related question (there it's asked opposite): http://stackoverflow.com/q/6621166/783119

Comment: BTW -- what sort of differences IDE detects? Content difference .. or (possibly) the difference in timestamp only?

Comment: @LazyOne I guess mine is the exact case you described above(related to timestamp) but I still can find no way in Webstorm settings to prevent this popup dialog. The opposite asked question did not help.

Comment: @narek I have never faced such situation myself so hard to say what may be causing it (I mean -- I never seen it showing up out of blue while I'm working in IDE). I've only faced it when I was editing some file outside of IDE (so switching between apps takes place). As for you -- please check what you may find in the idea.log (Help | Show Log in ...). Where your files are located BTW -- network drive or all are local? Any antivirus solutions running? Any tools that do constant backup?

Comment: @LazyOne I am just collaborating with the floobits plugin and me and my partner have scss watcher setup.I guess everytime I save a file, partner's watcher trigger the change to me back(because it watches the the file).  I do see contents are identical. I read somewhere that timestamp could be the problem, but I am not sure.

Comment: @narek Well yes -- time stamp + file size is the first thing that file system watcher (the thing that detects these changes) notices. You may try deleting such process so it does not start up (on Windows it would be `fsnotifier.exe` and `fsnotifier64.exe`). Obviously, it may work until next IDE update.

Comment: @LazyOne I've renamed both executables and errors are still popping up