# Docker container doesn't reload Angular app

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, containers

I have some issue with `ng serve` in my docker container running by `docker-compose`.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:7.1

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g angular-cli
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 4200

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]'
```

And my docker-compose.yml

```
web:
    build: .
    ports:
        - '8089:4200'
    volumes:
        - .:/usr/src/app/
    environment:
        - NODE_ENV=dev
    command: bash -c "npm start"
```

Everything works great when I run it but the editing file does not rise reload of application. File is changed, I'm sure because I check it by ssh connection and the file in the container is edited. When container is restarted again every change is applied.
I thought when I switch with building image by only docker to compose this will disappearr, but do not.

When I call touch some file from `docker exec` `webpack` reload all file and it work without restarting container.

Someone have solution?

Comment: Just to note, traditionally I've seen `NODE_ENV` as: `production` or `development`. Not `dev`.

Comment: @marckassay It can be user defined, you could have anything as `NODE_ENV`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I found solution for both problems:

1. inotify -> just edit `package.json` in `"scripts"` section this line: `"start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --poll"`, required only for Windows host,
2. hot reload -> add `expose 49153` in `Dockerfile` and ports `- '49153:49153'` in `docker-compose.yml` like @kstromeiraos mentioned.

Comment: Are you running windows? I tried this exact scenario but keep getting `web_1  | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.json'`

Comment: In my case VS2017 broke the `start` command as it adds the assigned port automatically, resulting in `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --poll "--port" "<number>"`. I had to specify poll time in ms after the `--poll` argument.

Comment: Actually, I just tried specifying just the `--poll` arg. and it works. There was no need for me to specify `--host 0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Started working after modifying step 1 to `"start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --poll 500"`

Comment: @NishanChathuranga Your solution works fantastically in visual studio 2019 without specifying host. `"start": "ng serve --poll 500",` Thanks.

Comment: Thanks gargi. I'm using mac and i exposed port 49153 which worked perfectly for me. Now watch functionality is working properly.

Answer (score 19):

Webpack uses a port to do live reload of the application. That port is `49153` by default.

You have to expose and bind that port in the container to the host port and that should solve your problem.

So, add this to your `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM node:7.1

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g angular-cli
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 4200 49153

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]'
```

And this to your `docker-compose.yml`.

```
web:
    build: .
    ports:
        - '8089:4200'
        - '49153:49153'
    volumes:
        - .:/usr/src/app/
    environment:
        - NODE_ENV=dev
    command: bash -c "npm start"
```

Comment: It's working on OS X or Linux host. But I'm developing it on Windows 10 host and host doesn't inotify file change. So you resolve my one problem with exposing port, now I will find solution for inotify on Windows host. Maybe do you have some solution for this too?

Answer (score 15):

My solution using node:slim.

No need for copying data into containers. Just use volumes.

Dockerfile:

**NOTE**: `--poll 1`

```
FROM node:slim

RUN npm install @angular/cli@latest -g

RUN mkdir -p /home/boilerplate

WORKDIR /home/boilerplate

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ng serve --port 4200 --host 0.0.0.0 --poll 1
```

Compose:

```
  project:
    image: project
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: projectdir/Dockerfile
    volumes:
    - ./projectdir:/home/boilerplate
    ports:
    - 4200:4200
```

Comment: Though I haven't taken complete solution but --poll 1 worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

A solution can be the chokidar wrapper, which is a dependency of the angular package. I dont know, if that was the status in 2017.
You don't need to expose any extra ports. Just use an environment variable in your docker-compose.

**Basic configuration:**

Dockerfile

```
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

docker-compose.yml

```
environment:
  - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

This should hot-reloading your browser. Tested on Chrome and Angular 8

Package for further investigation: https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar

Comment: Works! Tested on Angular CLI: 11.0.5, Node: 12.16.1, OS: win32 x64

Answer (score 2):

Another solution without polling.

**Background:**

I work on large Angular and React projects, the polling even every 10 seconds (`--poll 10000`) produce a lot of network traffic (in task manager you can check performance of docker nat interface). And in turn it produces high CPU load.

**Solution:**

If you use phpStorm/other Intellij produce or VS code you can add File watchers. I wrote the following script that helps me with this:

```
#!/bin/bash

image="${*:1:1}"
file="${*:2}"
machine=$(docker ps --filter ancestor="$image" --format "{{.ID}}")

if [ -n "$machine" ]
  then
    docker exec "$machine" touch "$file"
fi
```

After that I added following File Watcher (notice that the Trigger is switched off on external events):
[image]

**Notes:**
It is important that your `docker exec` has no parameter `-it` as tty or interactive parameters requires to use `winpty` (located where git bash is installed).
Also this solution is not Angular specific it is more docker specific, works the same for any webpack-dev-server app.

Also, phpStorm periodically shows `File Cache Conflict` dialog about file difference. To disable this prompt one can switched off file sync. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6628645

Comment: Hi, your solution looks efficient, but where should we put the script to? Could you elaborate more?

Comment: @budiantoip I do not remember anymore where I have put it. Probably inside the same repo and added it to .gitignore. But after that I switched to WSL2 + Deployments in phpStorm to linux subsystem. And that is best approach for me atm.
For VScode using WSL2 is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all answers, so I create a working example for 2021 (tested on Windows machine).

**STEP 1:**
Create new Angular project using Angular CLI

**STEP 2:**
Add new script in package.json

```
"start:dev": "npx ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --poll"
```

*Use `npx ng ...` so you don't have to install Angular CLI globally in Dockerfile.*

**STEP 3:**
Create Dockerfile inside Angular root project folder

```
FROM node:12-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install --silent
```

**STEP 4:**
Create docker-compose.yml outside Angular project folder (so you can add further services later)

```
version: '3'
services:
  angular:
    build:
      context: ./angular
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: npm run start:dev
    volumes:
      - ./angular:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
```

So you can open your local sourcecode, edit and see the changes on localhost:4200.

Hopefully, this answer helps some people.

Comment: This was extremely helpful. I was missing mounting `node_modules` again and `--poll` option. Your answer saved a lot of my time.

Answer (score 1):

This [Angular Docker Hot-Reload Template](https://github.com/Rehost-Startup/template-angular) works. It has all the relevant flags needed:

- `--disable-host-check`
- `--poll 2000`
  Just for confirmed host environment, `HOST=0.0.0.0` is passed.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

As they say [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62780245/nodemon-and-webpack-dev-server-hot-reload-not-working-under-wsl-2-after-windows)
If you're using a windows environment you should use an Angular in a docker development container, your project files should be inside a linux file system (WSL 2) to make it work, so you don't need the `--poll` flag, works for me.

**Original**

Hello I was struggling for a few hours with this problem. It was watching only the `package.json` file (I don't know why) and nothing more. I tried everything, then I found this question and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69811903/angular-ng-build-watch-in-remote-containers-and-remote-wsl-not-detecting-file), and the conclusion is that the `--poll 1` flag is the solution.

It works for me on Angular 16 and Node 18.