# Reloading MEAN stack application Docker-compose file err: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mean-stack, volumes

I have a MEAN stack application running on three Docker containers (MongoDB, Express, Angular). I would like to see immediate changes made to the angular app. I tried to follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44176922/docker-container-doesnt-reload-angular-app) but got the following error with the Angular container:

```
no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.json'
```

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3' # specify docker-compose version

# Define the services/containers to be run
services:
  angular: # name of the first service
    build: angular-src # specify the directory of the Dockerfile
    command: npm start
    ports:
      - "4200:4200" # specify port forewarding
      - "49153:49153"
    volumes:
      - ./angular-src:/usr/src/app

  express: #name of the second service
    build: . # specify the directory of the Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000" #specify ports forewarding
    links:
      - mongodb # link this service to the database service

  mongodb: # name of the third service
    image: mongo
    command: mongod --smallfiles
    ports:
      - 27017 # specify port forewarding

  mongo_seed:
    build: ./mongo_seed
    links:
      - mongodb
```

And my docker file for the Angular app:

```
# Create image based on the official Node 6 image from dockerhub
FROM node:8.9.1

# Create a directory where our app will be placed
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

# Change directory so that our commands run inside this new directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy dependency definitions
COPY package.json /usr/src/app

# Install dependecies
RUN npm install

# Get all the code needed to run the app
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Expose the port the app runs in
EXPOSE 4200 49153

# Serve the app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the result of the `COPY` commands in your Dockerfile with the `volumes` element in your angular service in the docker-compose.yml.

`COPY package.json /usr/src/app`

Contents of /usr/src/app: package.json

`COPY . /usr/src/app`

Contents of /usr/src/app: (whatever is included in build context at .), packages.json

When you `docker-compose up` and the angular service is ran, a volume is mounted:

```
volumes:
     - ./angular-src:/usr/src/app
```

Contents of /usr/src/app: (everything in angular-src)

When you mount a volume, you aren't adding the files from the volume to the files in the container, you're replacing the directory wholesale.

Comment: Thank for the reply. After the volume is mounted you said the content is 'everything in angular-src', this the package.json should also be the right? Not sure I completely understood...

Comment: if ./angular-src/package.json exists on your host, yes. If not, no. Take a peek in the container: `docker run -it <your_angular_image> /bin/bash`, and check the contents of /usr/src/app. If it looks ok, mimic the volume mount from your compose: `docker run -it -v $(pwd)/angular-src:/usr/src/app <your_angular_image> /bin/bash`, and check again to make sure things are as you expect them to be.