# Nodemon and webpack-dev-server hot reload not working under WSL 2 after Windows 10 resinstall

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nodemon, hot-reload

A few days ago I re-installed Windows 10. I am developing full stack web app with express as backend and React.js as frontend. I am using nodemon to realod the server and webpack-dev-server for the frontend. Worth mentioning is that I am using WSL2. I noticed that nodemon has no reaction upon saving a file. I had to manually type `rs` to reload. At first thought it is a problem with nodemon. Looked for similar question here, but all I found was `--watch`, which did not help. Not that I've tried webpack and the issue persists I am clueless. Here is some useful info:
**webpack command**:
`webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development`.

**webpack.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./app/index.jsx"],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ["babel-loader"],
            },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"] },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
                loader: "file-loader",
                options: {
                    name: "[path][name].[hash].[ext]",
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            components: __dirname + "/app/components",
            reducers: __dirname + "/app/reducers",
            constants: __dirname + "/app/constants",
            actions: __dirname + "/app/actions",
            store: __dirname + "/app/store",
            styles: __dirname + "/app/styles",
            assets: __dirname + "/app/assets/",
            api: __dirname + "/app/api/",
        },
        enforceExtension: false,
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/public",
        publicPath: "/",
        filename: "index.js",
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: "./public",
        port: 8080,
    },
};
```

Also both of these are working fine on Linux laptop and were fine before the re-installation.

Comment: Try re-install nodemon in global state. Npm install -g nodemon

Comment: @Phemieny007 Just tried it, but didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured this out on my own. Just posting it here in case somebody encounters the same issue. The difference between my system now and before the re-installation is that I upgraded to WSL2. For some reason nodemon and webpack-dev-server hot reload does not work in WSL2. Downgrading to WSL 1 resolved the issue.

EDIT: In order for this to work in WSL 2, the project needs to be inside the linux file system.

Comment: Thanks much for following up. This is helpful. I don't want to bury my files in a hard-to-access virtual machine. Once again poor OS-craft is patched with a "recommendation". Hopefully we won't lose this capability altogether.

Comment: For my rails app which I had setup in the WSL2 (Ubuntu 18.04 distro), the webpack-dev-server would not be able to watch the modifications to the files which are not inside Ubunutu. So I moved it in the home directory of the Ubuntu, and now it was able to respond to the file changes and compile them. I was using Sublime text on Windows for development, so to access that project, I used the path `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\home\<user>\projects` to open in Sublime text.

Comment: > the project needs to be inside the linux file system. <

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  watchOptions: {
    poll: 1000 // Check for changes every second
  }
};
```

[Watch and WatchOptions](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/)

Or move your files into WSL filesystem:

```
\\wsl$\<distroname>\home\<username>
```

Comment: +1 for moving the files into the WSL2 filesystem. What's odd is that I had npm auto-reloading within WSL2 just a few days ago, DESPITE the files existing outside of the WSL2 filesystem. That being said, MS recommends against working across filesystems https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions#performance-across-os-file-systems

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
webpack -w --watch-poll
```